# Dual type of return value

Tags: dm-script

all:
I'd like to construct a function. The type of return value may have two possibilities: number or string. At first, I thought I can use the overloading function (see the code). But this function must have different type of input. So the belowing code will get error. Is there any feasible and easy way to solve this problem?

```
Number tmp(String a)
{
if (a == "a") return 1
}

String tmp(String a)
{
if (a == "b") return "a"
}

Result(tmp("a"))
Result(tmp("b"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike's answer using objects is a good one, but if you're only interested in "simple" data type returns, I would rather suggest that you use the TagGroup object as return value. You can essentially store any information in a TagGroup and even add some structure to it. But also: Even a single tag can be written as f.e. number but read out as a string and vice versa. (It will perform the "typical" type casting or number<>string interpretations.)

Answer (score 2):

You have discovered two limitations of the DM script language. The first is that functions cannot have multiple return values, as they can in Python. The other is that all functions with a given name and list of argument types (i.e. a given function prototype) can only have a single return type.

One way to get around these limitations is to make use of the fact that DM functions can return objects, rather than just a simple numeric or string value. Since an object can contain multiple member variables (of various types), this allows one to return multiple values with a single function call. One can do this either by using TagGroup objects or by defining and using a custom script Object type.

The following example re-implements your tmp function using a TagGroup return value:

```
TagGroup tmp(String a)
{
    TagGroup returnData = NewTagGroup();
    if (a == "a")
        returnData.TagGroupSetTagAsNumber("Returned number", 1);
    else if (a == "b")
        returnData.TagGroupSetTagAsString("Returned string", "a");
    
    return returnData;
}

Number numericResult;
String stringResult;
TagGroup result = tmp("a");
if (result.TagGroupGetTagAsNumber("Returned number", numericResult))
    Result("Numeric result: " + numericResult + "\n");
else if (result.TagGroupGetTagAsString("Returned string", stringResult))
    Result("String result: " + stringResult + "\n");
```

Here is another example that does the equivalent with a custom script Object defined by the TmpReturnData class:

```
class TmpReturnData
{
    Number isNumeric;
    Number numericResult;
    String stringResult;

    Object Init(Object self, Number numericReturnValue)
    {
        isNumeric = 1;
        numericResult = numericReturnValue;
    
        return self;
    }

    Object Init(Object self, String stringReturnValue)
    {
        isNumeric = 0;
        stringResult = stringReturnValue;
    
        return self;
    }

    Number IsNumericResult(Object self)
        return isNumeric;

    Number GetNumericResult(Object self)
        return numericResult;

    String GetStringResult(Object self)
        return stringResult;
}

Object tmp(String a)
{
    Object returnData;
    if (a == "a")
        returnData = Alloc(TmpReturnData).Init(1);
    else if (a == "b")
        returnData = Alloc(TmpReturnData).Init("a");
    
    return returnData;
}

void main()
{
    Object result = tmp("a");
    if (result.ScriptObjectIsValid())
    {
        if (result.IsNumericResult())
            Result("Numeric result: " + result.GetNumericResult() + "\n");
        else
            Result("String result: " + result.GetStringResult() + "\n");
    }
}

main();
```

The thing to keep in mind is that DM script is a strongly typed language. Any variable used within a given scope of a script must be declared to have a single and definite type. This is again in contrast to Python, which allows variable types to be more fluid. Some think of this as a limitation, others find this to be a strength of the DM script language because it allows the interpreter to catch many common types of bugs and helps one arrive at a correctly executing program more quickly.